# How to get the changed url to post data?

Tags: python, python-requests

I want to get the json data from the [website][1]. Now I get the list of job p_ordNo. I want to get the detail of the job. I found it used post methold.So,I use request post data like this:

```
url = "https://www2.jobs.gov.hk/1/0/WebServices/QuickviewWS.asmx/F_GetJobCardDetail"
postdata = {'p_ordNo': card,'p_langOpt': '3','p_liveOnly': ''}
scode = requests.post(url, data = postdata,timeout=30).status
```

It return code 502 like this

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

[![enter image description here][3]][3]

I found the posturl is changed, but I don't know how to get the changed url.

Comment: This looks like it is missing a URL and two image references.

Comment: you may have to use `Session()` to get `coockies` on main page and later send requests with `cookies`. You can also may need to use the same  `headers` as in web browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure all of these steps are necessary but this is how I got it working, please read the comments in the code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json

# use requests.session() to capture cookies.
session = requests.session()

# Set some headers it needs at least some of these.
headers={'User-Agent':"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv'\:'57.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/57.0",
'Accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*','Accept-Language': 'en-GB,en;q=0.8,fr;q=0.6,es;q=0.4,pl;q=0.2',
'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
'Referer':'http://www1.jobs.gov.hk/1/0/WebForm/jobseeker/jobsearch/quickview.aspx?ResetTimeStamp=true&SearchFor=jobtype&id=1',
'Content-Type':' application/json; charset=utf-8',
'X-Requested-With':'XMLHttpRequest',
'Connection':' keep-alive'}

# Make a GET request to get the value we use for p_ordNo later.
url = "http://www2.jobs.gov.hk/1/0/WebForm/jobseeker/jobsearch/quickview.aspx?ResetTimeStamp=true&SearchFor=jobtype&id=1"
page = session.get(url, headers=headers).text

# Read the value we use for p_ordNo later.
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "lxml")
value = soup.find("input", {"name": "ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$uxSelectedOrdNo"})["value"]

# Make the POST request it is not JSON as it is not quoted correctly.
url = "http://www2.jobs.gov.hk/1/0/WebServices/Quickview3WS.asmx/F_GetJobCardDetail"

# get the response as a JSON object
result = session.post(url, headers=headers, data = "{{p_ordNo:'{}',p_langOpt: '3',p_liveOnly: ''}}".format(value),timeout=30).json()

#Print the result.
print (json.dumps(result, indent=4, sort_keys=True, ensure_ascii=False))
```

Answer (score 0):

I modified the requests,like this:

```
postdata = {'p_ordNo': card,
            'p_langOpt': '3',
            'p_liveOnly': ''}

session.post(url, data = json.dumps(postdata),headers=headers).content
```

Now it's working

Not

```
session.post(url, data = postdata,headers=headers).content
```